# Regex - sed to extract word between patterns

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to extract the word `hello` from `ENC(hello)` using `sed`.

I've tried the following but so far no joy:

```
 property="ENC(hello)" && echo "$property" | sed 's/(?<=^ENC\()(.*)(?=\))/\1/'
```

Can you advise what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
property="ENC(hello)" && echo "$property" | sed -e 's/ENC(\(.*\))/\1/'
```

the problem is that sed seems to not support the "lazy" match but to be always greedy, so if in one line you have

```
ENC(hello) ENC(world)
```

such regex won't help

Comment: To get rid of all incidences of 'ENC()':
`property="ENC(hello) ENC(world)" && echo "$property" | sed -e 's/ENC(//g; s/)//g'`

Comment: A common workaround to do a non greedy match when the stop pattern is a single character is to use a negated bracket, here `[^)]*` instead of `.*`.